# Include Iverson Bracket in R documentation

Tags: r, documentation, latex, package, roxygen2

I am wanting to include an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) in R documentation (unless there's a better way to represent this information; I'm no mathematician).  This looks something like this.

[image]

Here I have valid LaTeX code for such an expression

```
w_{neg}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \sum{(X_i^{N})}>0 \\ 
0 & \sum{(X_i^{N}})=0
\end{matrix}\right.
```

I tried to include the code below:

```
#' w_{neg}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
#' 1 & \sum{(X_i^{N})}>0 \\ 
#' 0 & \sum{(X_i^{N}})=0
#' \end{matrix}\right.
```

in the details section of `roxygen2` but it produces the error seen below when compiling the pdf help documentation:

```
Creating pdf output from LaTeX ...
Warning: running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe"  --pdf "Rd2.tex"  -I "C:/R/R-30~1.1/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/R/R-30~1.1/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
Error : running 'texi2dvi' on 'Rd2.tex' failed

LaTeX errors:
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> \left \{\begin {matrix} 1 &
                                       \sum {(X_i^{N})}>0 \\ 0 & \sum {(X_i^...
l.5566   \sum{(X_i^{N}})=0 \end{matrix}\right.}{}

! Emergency stop.
<argument> \left \{\begin {matrix} 1 &
                                       \sum {(X_i^{N})}>0 \\ 0 & \sum {(X_i^...
l.5566   \sum{(X_i^{N}})=0 \end{matrix}\right.}{}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
```

How can I include this Iverson Bracket in R documentation (unless there's a better way to represent this in which case that's the better approach)?  Note that removal of these lines allows the package to compile.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `\begin{array}{cc}...\end{array}`

Comment: @mnel First time working with this, but as seen below this was the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I utilized the following in the roxygen2 documentation and it worked:

```
#' \deqn{w_{neg}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
#' 1 & \sum{(X_i^{N})}>0         \\ 
#' 0 & \sum{(X_i^{N}})=0
#' \end{array}\right.}
```